# jQuery split textarea content into two textareas at a particular line number

Tags: jquery, html

I  need to split textarea content into two textareas at a particular line number of the content using jQuery. Can this be done?

I googled but couldn't find anything. jQuery's pretty powerful, I would have thought this can be done.

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

C

Comment: those lines separated by "\n" or enter button?

Comment: lines seperated by `\r\n`

Comment: Here's how I would go about this. 1. `split` the contents of your textarea where there's a `\r\n`. That will make you an array with as many elements as there were lines in the textarea. 2. `empty` the textarea. 3. Iterate over your array to put yourArray[0]+'\r\n'+yourArray[1]+'\r\n' etc. in your first text area, up until yourArray[x], x being the number of lines you want in your first textarea (minus one?). 4. Do pretty much the same trick with the rest of the array with textarea number two.

Comment: i posted my answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this code,**

```
<select id='lineSelector'>
    <option>- select line -</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<br/>
<textarea id='tarea' cols='40' rows='5'>first line second line third fourth fifth</textarea>
<textarea id="newarea" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```

**javascript code,**

```
function selectTextareaLine(tarea, lineNum) {
    lineNum--; // array starts at 0
    var lines = tarea.value.split("\n");
// calculate start/end
var startPos = 0,
    endPos = tarea.value.length;
for (var x = 0; x < lines.length; x++) {
    if (x == lineNum) {
        break;
    }
    startPos += (lines[x].length + 1);

}
var final = tarea.value.substring(startPos, endPos);
tarea.value = tarea.value.replace(final,"");
}

/// debugging code
var sel = document.getElementById('lineSelector');
var tarea = document.getElementById('tarea');
sel.onchange = function () {
    selectTextareaLine(tarea, this.value);
}
```

**SEE FIDDLE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/xCE9G/5/)**

Comment: That's awesome thanks @CJ Ramki. How do I egt it to remove the copied text from the first box. I need it to `move` not `copy`. Thanks again for the help.